# Modifying biblatex not display accents in Latin locutions

Tags: biblatex

I'm finishing my thesis written in latex using the biblatex package.

Getting picky about the details, my friend told me that it is not correct to use `Ibíd.` or `óp.cit.`, note the small accents. I'm using the option to put these Latin terms in italic. They are in their original language and in latin there are no accents. How do i patch the package to stop putting these latin locutions with an accent.

It should be `op. cit.` or `Ibid`.

I'm writing in spanish, using xetex and the polyglossia package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish,letter,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\OnehalfSpacing
\makeatletter

\usepackage[autocite=footnote,natbib=true,style=verbose-trad2,backend=bibtex8,isbn=false,dashed=false,maxcitenames=2,ibidem=idem,idemtracker=false,style=verbose-trad2,ibidpage=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{citastesis.bib}
\bibliography{biblatex_style_guide}

\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph} %% for italics in ibidem


 \begin{document}
   Text 1, text 2, \autocite{cite1}.
   Paragraph2, \autocite{cite1}.

 \end{document}
```

Edit: I add the MWE.

Comment: I disagree with the person who has put in a close-this-posting request because the posting is supposedly off-topic for this site. The question is about how to use `biblatex` -- which is a major LaTeX package -- properly; I do not understand why this would be considered to be off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post not only a description of the problem, but an actual MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that reproduces the problem you're looking to fix.

Comment: Also, can i change the french quotes (>>) for the english ones ("")?, in my country we don't use these french quotes, but they get inside my citations.

Comment: about the quotes: see package `csquotes` and its manual.

Answer (score 4):

In your case I would write my own language file for biblatex:

Create a new document in your current projectfolder with the name `spanish-custom.lbx`:

```
\ProvidesFile{spanish-custom.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{spanish}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit   = {spanish},
  ibidem           = {{ibidem}{ibid\adddot}},%modified
  opcit            = {{op\adddotspace cit\adddot}{op\adddotspace cit\adddot}},%modified
}
```

That will inherit all strings from the default spanish language file, but modify the two strings for `ibidem` and `opcit`.

Then add in your preamble:
`\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-custom}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-custom}

\begin{document}

Nietzsche said...\autocite{nietzsche:historie} and then ...\autocite{nietzsche:historie}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to compile with the above example both using babel and polyglossia, but texlive dind't find the custom .lbx file. The file is in my compilation folder. It doesn't work, do i have to put it in the tex tree, or under the local tex tree?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe this depends on your environment. I'm using MikTeX, it finds the custom lbx in my compilation folder. Try to put it in the lbx-folder from biblatex. Maybe you have to insert an `\input{spanish-custom}` in the `biblatex.cfg`. Another way is, *simulate* the file with the package `filecontents`.

Comment: I just went eh ugly and dirty way and modified the spanish.lbx present in my tex tree under the directory biblatex. I'm using texlive, in my linux distro (arch) this file is located in: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx. I just edited the file and removed manually any sign of the ´ character. Of course this is not the best solution as this is not portable. But i think is the same as puting spanish custom under the tex tree. Of course I backed up the original spanish.lbx file. Shouldn't the file be patched???

Comment: I agree with the lbx-file. I'm using `filecontents` to simulate an extra lbx-file, that works fine, too. (If you get warnings, use the `silence`-package). If it's not common for spanish bibliographies/citation to use `´`-characters, you maybe should contact the maintainer of the biblatex package. If my answer did solve your problem, please mark it as accepted answer.